Would a photon engine work?
So as far as I know for a body to move in space it needs to accelerate using it's mass because there is nothing else to push against. And as far as I understand, basically, the photon engine is an engine that emits light, and that light should theoretically push body through space. Photons are fast but they do not have mass. Therefore it won't really work in practice right? Or are there any other nuances that are subject to doubt it's theoretical non-workability?

Have you heard of solar sails?

Photons have momentum. I have some equations related to a photon engine here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/345492/123208
