Eternal Acceleration
I'm a physics graduate, so I have a solid understanding of special but not much knowledge of general relativity. I tried a thought experiment the other day involving a spacecraft accelerating continuously at 1g. By my reckoning it would take around a year to begin approaching light speed but I couldn't understand the dynamics in this scenario. Specifically, given that it cant breach the 'light barrier' would the passengers begin to experience less acceleration (intuitively this does not seem right to me) and what is the 'light barrier' measured with respect to anyway given that SR tells us it is a constant for all observers. I understand that the ship would gain super-luminal velocities relative to ,say, the background stars but how would relativity affect its acceleration? Obviously I am neglecting the influence of mass and radiation on the ship.

Your scenario involves a flat (zero-spacetime-curvature) spacetime: Special Relativity is sufficient, but one likely has to use more advanced formulas beyond those in an intro textbook. General relativity isn't needed.

Usually in such scenarios, when we say the ship is accelerating continuously at 1 g, then it feels like constant 1 g gravity to the passengers. Such a ship consumes a lot of fuel. I have some related analysis here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/345492/123208

As the ship goes to c, its mass goes to infinity , so its more and more difficult to accelerate with g, Tats what determins the limit, thats why you need so much energy to even only accelerate  protons to near c.

I think I get it now: the time dilation effect means that the ship can produce more power in the lab frame while maintaining the same output onboard.
