Can human body be accelerated to 99% of the speed of light?
I wrote a comment at Hacker News to say that human body could not be accelerated to close to the speed of light. There were several comments saying that this was possible. Can you please help?

Can the human body be accelerated to 99% of the speed of light? I'm not asking as a thought experiment, I'm asking in practice.
If humans could be accelerated to the 99% of the speed of light without bodily damage, how long would that take? I understand that to increase our speed to 99% of the speed of light we need to do it with gentle accelerations. Assume that we are astronauts in a space ship and we have enough fuel to reach 99% of the speed of light. How long would it take for us to reach 99% of the speed of light?
Since only massless particles can go with the speed of light how do we make the human body massless?

Edit: As my comment to @The Photon, the third question should be read as: Only massless particles will and must travel with the speed of light. Human body is not a massless particle. The logical question to ask is how can human body can reach the speed of light if it is not a massless particle?
I apologize if these are too elementary questions. Thanks

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Can the human body be accelerated to the speed of light?

No. It can be accelerated very, very close to the speed of light, but not actually to the speed of light.
You're thinking of these two cases as equivalent, but to physicists there's a very important distinction between "the speed of light" and "something really close to the speed of light".

I'm not asking as a thought experiment, I'm asking in practice.

In practice, it depends on having enough energy available to do it, and to also accelerate a living environment to keep the human alive while they travel in space, and also on being able initially to accelerate the fuel that you're going to use for further acceleration later.
With our current technology, it's not practically possible, but that does not mean it couldn't be done in principle.

how long would that take?

Someone in this Reddit thread calculated, for a 1g acceleration,


Your rapidity would increase linearly. 0.99 c corresponds to a rapidity of artanh(0.99)=2.65. You have to accelerate for a time where you would reach 2.65 times the speed of light in Newtonian mechanics, or 920 days.


As pointed out in the Reddit thread, this is in the traveller's frame. In the initial reference frame (i.e. the Earth's frame) it's about 2484 days (hat tip to @PM2Ring in comments).

Since only massless particles can go with the speed of light how do we make the human body massless?

We can't. If we did, it wouldn't make sense to call the result a "human body" any more.

"We can't. If we did, it wouldn't make sense to call the result a "human body" any more." So, there is only one conclusion I can draw from this sentence: human body cannot be accelerated to the 99% of the speed of light and remain a human body. Explain what I'm missing here.

No, I didn't say that. The human body can't be accelerated to 100% of the speed of light because it is not massless. Again the distinction between "speed of light" and "almost the speed of light" is very important in physics. You can't just assume the rules for one are the same as the rules for the other.

Using a constant acceleration of g=9.80665 m/s^2, 920 days would get you up to ~93.33534% c. To get to 99% c takes slightly under 2484 days.

@PM2Ring in the Reddit thread it's pointed out that the value of 920 days is measured in the traveller's frame.

Ah, ok. I didn't read the thread.

@PM2Ring, NBD, it was worthwhile adding that information here.

"also on being able initially to accelerate the fuel that you're going to use for further acceleration later" Although depending on how it's done you might not be carrying your power source.

@J.G., true, but can any of those methods reach 0.99c? The ramjet is limited to 0.12c. I expect a solar sail would run out of "wind" before reaching 0.99c. Etc.

The proper time (ship clock time) is ~936.6 days.

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlkE9vm0AQxe98iid6AFwCGNsUrGxUpapVJaoUEZ8TDcsGo%5FIngVEUZOW7V8umB5rLauftm9%2DbnS%5F40XcjU8cgKVWjBuK671B3uM99FBPufiPO664KEEfxNlhHQZRZEgJxln3L4u0utUqaIJAm2yiyJkWDKbDCJtnFO8v6XnesBpJsleoJjy6%5FsfjFbXPdv7n25WlzdZ8v0i%5FD0%2DbK9nwUNY8ijXyQyII0SpLd4IOFE29TjS9pcry9BQD5AQK5ouZQq6Z0daM3P5DWDy6Zik01UqUe1Ss1LvtoeknNKM6Oxu1Lmnw4%2DhfOXp%5Fvnul8HuqO3SdbE868DxL1jlHJuQpLmoxiNnHmULcaSd9swyggQFiBEULOSgWB8WVgd42vKB7iD59iPXaBENUi%5FFXD59cVpMG34fhPNIK0lwNX1LaaphPO1cV6dv3nuf2pGfIhxgpuhQusPQO7Cf9UH96jHn6su5NbeDoeIWgBuRv6ZzWA61Zp2nGxo%2DOnHR0%5F7%2DgvQ420dw==&lang=sage

A ship at 1 g, with a perfect antimatter engine carrying its own fuel, has a "half-life" of ~35 weeks (~245.25154 days). That is, it consumes half its mass every 35 weeks (ship time). See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/345492/123208 for details.

"can any of those methods reach 0.99c?" I imagine beamed propulsion could.

I will be accepting your answer but another constraint occurred to me. If the rocket is launched from the earth (as we assumed realistic initial conditions) how can we go around Kepler’s third law?  Am I wrong in assuming that as we increase the radius of the orbit our speed will decrease. In order to increase our speed we need to decrease our orbital radius. Even if we assume that the earth has a radius of 1 km (and the same mass) the most we can accelerate is 0.2 percent of the speed of light. What am I missing here?

@zeynel, Kepler's laws are for un-propelled bodies in orbit. They don't have anything to do with bodies being accelerated by forces other than gravity. You can simply accelerate your body away from the Earth (and the Sun) on a trajectory that doesn't follow a ballistic orbit, for as long as you want, if you want to approach light speed.


I know we cannot reach the speed of light, let's say 99% of speed of light.

You're already doing it! There exists a reference frame where you are moving at 99% of the speed of light right now.
If you mean relative to an "initial" rest frame, then you can easily calculate how much energy you need to do this for $v=0.99c$
$$K=(\gamma-1)mc^2\approx 6mc^2$$
This is a lot of energy, but you can take this with whatever method you're thinking of to also see how long it would take, resources needed, etc.

OP asked how long (how much time) it would take, not how much energy.

Your comment about there being no absolute reference frame is most interesting. Just further evidence confirming Einstein; "All the stars in the universe can be thought of as taking part in the generation of the gravitational field. While in SR a portion of space is truly empty, it is quite different in GR. Empty space has physical qualities characterized by the components of gravitation that determine the behavior of that portion of space as well as its gravitational field." Thus the gravitational field does indeed provide an absolute frame of reference.

@ThePhoton the OP has not given enough information for me to find that for them

@foolishmuse edited

@foolishmuse Do you have the reference for this Einstein quote? I'd like to read in context.

@zeynel  Einstein "Dialogue about objections to the theory of relativity".   https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Dialog_about_Objections_against_the_Theory_of_Relativity

Interesting article. Thanks. Einstein wrote a dialogue in the style of Galileo.



Can the human body be accelerated to 99% of the speed of light?


Yes.


If humans could be accelerated to the 99% of the speed of light
without bodily damage, how long would that take?


From the equations of the relativistic rocket it is fairly easy to derive that the time to accelerate to v/c = 0.99 with constant acceleration of 1g is:
$$t = \frac {v}{g\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} }\approx 2483  \ \text{days}$$
of coordinate time. (Wolfram Alpha calculation here) Similarly we can derive:
$$T = \frac{c}{g} \  \tanh^{-1} \left(\frac vc\right) \approx 936 \  \text{days}$$
of proper or in other words how much the traveller ages.
(Wolfram Alpha calculation here)


Since only massless particles can go with the speed of light how do we
make the human body massless?


It is not possible to make the human body massless, unless you somehow changed all the mass of the body into light and it would no longer be a human.

The logical question to ask is how can human body can reach the speed
of light if it is not a massless particle?

The logical answer is that it is not possible for the human body to reach the speed of light.
